# What are the differences between built-in terminals in Neovim and Vim?

Tags: neovim, terminal, terminal-buffer, original-vim

AFAIK the main difference is that Vim has this `:terminal` feature as optional. Could you mention another other important differences?

Comment: What do you mean by "terminal emulator"? Do you mean the `:terminal` command?

Answer (score 1):

In recent version of Neovim and Vim both are pretty similar.

Differences that I'm aware off is that:

- Windows management:

  - Vim creates an horizontal split for the `terminal` buffer vs.
  - Neovim reuse the current Window.
- Initial Mode:

  - Vim starts the terminal in `Terminal` mode (ready to enter commands) vs.
  - Neovim starts the terminal in `Normal` mode (type `i` to switch to `Terminal` mode)

Apart from that I'm not aware of differences.

Comment: I think the implementation might also differ and the options that you can give to the `:terminal` command are different as well

Comment: Also the related programming APIs